# Can I apply for my UK ancestry visa while working in South Africa for a UK company, or do I need to live in the UK?

Tags: visa, uk-visa, working, south-african-citizens, ancestry-visas

I have a remote job in SA working online for a UK based company.
Can I apply for my UK ancestry visa from SA?

Comment: Why wouldn't you be able to apply from SA?

Answer (score 1):

> Can I apply for my UK ancestry visa while working in South Africa for a UK company, or do I need to live in the UK?

The ancestry visa is a document that allows you to move to the UK.  It wouldn't make sense to require you to apply for it in the UK.  Sure enough, from [the UK government pages](https://www.gov.uk/ancestry-visa/apply):

> ## Apply from outside the UK
>
> You must apply online for a UK Ancestry visa before you travel to the UK.